# update number at the end of a line

Tags: bash, file, sed

I try to add a number at the end of each line for each files in a dir and update it.
Let's say: starting with 1 for the first file, 2 for the second file and so on.

The script I used is as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
   n=1 
for filename in $HOME/path/to/direc/*
 do
  sed -i 's/$/ $(($n + 1))/g' $filename
 done
```

The command I tough naively  works like that: add a space and a number at the end of each line of file $filename. The number is updated each time with the condition `$(($n + 1))`.
Instead it print out at the end of each line of each file: " $(($n + 1))" ...
The 'space', at the beginning it's ok, but not the number.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash doesn't interpolate strings in single quotes. Try double quotes instead.

Also, the `/g` is not needed, as `$` can only match once per line.

To update the variable value, you need to assign the new value to it

```
$(( n = n + 1 ))
```

or, shorter

```
$(( n += 1 ))
```

or, even shorter

```
$(( n++ ))
```

Comment: I change it with `sed -i "s/$/ $(($n + 1))/g" $filename` and it gave to me a number now (let's say 1) but it didn't update to 2,3,4...while passing to the other files.

Comment: Perfect. It was the answer! ;)